# .htaccess block users who type in the url directly instead of clicking on link

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to block non-linked url requests? As in if this didn't come from a link, but was typed directly into the URL bar, do not allow?

Answer (score 0):

If the http referrer is blank or has a domain other than the ones you want to allow (regex) then you deny them. This is not a good idea though. In my experience some software or crummy browsers do not send referrer data or send incorrect referrer data. Packets can also be faked using browser extensions or sending them directly. It's not a good idea. Plus if they click from your link, then refresh, it will often send the request without referrer.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless.

So with an .htaccess file you will not be able to achieve that. Easiest way would probably be to check for a referrer header. But understand that this can be "faked" to - it's more of a "security by obscurity" approach.